# Order table according to key in foreign key table

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have table `users`, and table `points`.

Table `points` has foreign key `user_id`, so I did this in my `User` Eloquent model:

```
public function points()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Point', 'user_id');
}
```

So now I can get number of points for one user by doing:

```
$user->points()->count();
```

But what I want to do is order all users according to points they won and then paginate users by 20 per page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will start from the inverse relationship:

```
$points = Point::with('User')
                 ->orderBy('votes', 'desc')
                 ->skip($offset)
                 ->take($page_size);    // or use ->paginate();
```

and then in your view:

```
@foreach($points as $point)
  {{ $point->votes }} | {{ $point->user->name }}
@endforeach
```

Note: make sure you define the inverse relationship in the `Point` model.

Comment: I have defined inverse relationship. Will try this and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: I don't have points as a number/column so I can order it. One record in table `points` is one point. So I need to count these points and than order users by that count result. Hope I'm not too confusing

Comment: I understand now what you are trying to achieve and I have no clear idea how could you do that with Eloquent, without using Fluent or raw SQL. But as a note from an architectural point of view, you should consider storing the count of votes in a column which will have its value incremented every time a given user gets a vote. This will not only allow you to implement what you want with Eloquent, but will also improve the performance because the table will not have to be re-scanned to calculate the count of records.